# Tor not running?

Tags: proxy, tor

I followed the Tor demo. I installed Polipo and configured it.  I restarted both Polipo and Tor services.

Before I had Tor set up, the following script failed.

```
 def fetch_url(url):
   proxy_support=urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http":"127.0.0.1:8118"})
   opener=urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
   opener.addheaders=[('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0')]
   html=opener.open(url).read()
   return html
```

Now it no longer raises an exception.  However, when I go to the Tor check page (see if tor is running), it tells me that Tor is not operational.  It also shows me my IP address.

https://check.torproject.org/

I've gotten Tor to work on Windows.  I've done so, though, through the GUI.  Any thoughts on what's going wrong here?

Thanks, 
Brendan

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux, which distro are you using?
Have you started the `tor` service?  For example on ArchLinux:  `$ /etc/rc.d/tor start && /etc/rc.d/polipo start`
Did you configure `polipo` to use `tor`?
What's the URL of the demo you talked about?